# compiler error: invalid use of undefined type 'union ...' . What is wrong in the definition?

Tags: c

My code is organized as following:

**File: main.c**

```
 #include "init.h"
 #include "SpiComm.h"
 //. . . .
```

**File:  init.h**

```
typedef union {

    unsigned int wholeReg;

    struct   {
        unsigned CMD1_flag: 1; 
            . . . .

    };

}  DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE;

extern volatile union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE DiscreteFlagsReg; //register declaration
```

**File: SpiComm.c**

```
#include "SpiComm.h"

volatile union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE  DiscreteFlagsReg;


unsigned char* SpiTxFrameSetup (void)
{
            . . . .                
    SpiTxMsgByte1.dt1CmdFlag = L_DiscreteFlagsReg.regBits.DT1_HW_CMD_flag;
            . . . . 
    spiTxMsg[4] = SpiTxMsgByte1.byte0Full;
        . . . . 
    return (spiTxMsg);  //return the pointer to Tx message array;
}
```

Compiler is notifying this for SpiComm.c file (and for any other .c file that attempts to use any field of this union):

error: invalid use of undefined type 'union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE'

What is wrong? Why other c files doesn't recognize the union type I've defined in init.h?

Comment: Yo don't have a tag on the union, but a `typedef`. Btw: Is that C or C++? Pick one! Semantics are different here.

Comment: And: `return` is not a function, but a statement. You should not add parenthesis here.

Comment: `union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE DiscreteFlagsReg` – you probably wanted `DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE DiscreteFlagsReg` instead.

Comment: Wonder why this was down voted?  Honest effort, good presentation, clearly presented question.

Answer (score 3):

The union itself has no name; "DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE" is a typedef name.

You can use the typedef name:

```
extern volatile DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE DiscreteFlagsReg;
```

or name the union:

```
union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE
{
   /* ... */
};
```

and use `union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE` in C, or `DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE` in C++

or, in C, combine the naming and the typedef:

```
typedef union DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE
{
   /* ... */
} DISCRETE_FLAGS_REG_TYPE;
```

(The last variant is an error in C++.)

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the definition and now it's ok.